# Is a trained cascade classifier needed to detect specific faces in Python3 OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to make a OpenCV program in Python 3 to detect the faces of my friends. I've seen that one can train a Cascade Classifier using OpenCV to specify a certain type of object. However, it isn't clear whether that could create a classifier refined enough to pick only my friends' faces out of a large sample size, or whether this is something I could achieve without making my own Cascade Classifier. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at https://pypi.org/project/face_recognition/

Answer (score 0):

Cascade classifiers usually are built for face detection. You are trying to solve a different problem, face recognition.

Deep learning is a common framework nowdays, but other models do exist. http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/ makes a very good job at presenting the main algorithms.

[This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/) presents an interesting implementation in OpenCV.